# Anki: How do I create a deck with data from two different sources?

Tags: anki

I have two sources of data:

1. A folder filled with images (in order)
2. A tab delimited text file

I want to build a deck that has the image on the front and the text on the back. However, I have approximately 300 such cards to make and making them manually would be time-consuming.

I have tried to `Import` the text file but all it can do is fill one side of the cards with text and leave the other side blank.

Similarly if I use the `Media Import` add-on, one side will be populated with the image, the other with the image-file name (which is useless for my purposes).

To reiterate, I need the card to have the image on the front side and the text on the back. Strange thing is, I've done this before, but I just can't remember how I did it (was years ago).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could give every card an individual number as tag (or you could use the ID Add-on) and also give the the picture just the number of the card, to which it should belong.
Then you could maybe reference in the note template this picture in a way like <img src="{{ID-number}}.jpg" >. 
If it does not work this direct way (as I suppose), someone could maybe write some javascript that extracts the ID number from the card field, assign the value to a variable, and use that variable instead in the image reference, so <img src="[[variable]].jpg"> . Unfortunately, I don't know much about javascript and how to extract that number. Maybe someone else can help you with that? I hope I could help you with my answer...

Answer (score 1):

I made a [program which might help](https://github.com/mattdp/pdf-to-anki), though it's not exactly similar. In my case, it's using an image as the question and multiple images as the answer, but the import is performed using a CSV with HTML-formatted questions and answers.

Example excerpt (format is "question, answer"):

```
<img src='Anatomic Sciences -0.jpg'>,<img src='Anatomic Sciences -1.jpg'><img src='Anatomic Sciences -2.jpg'><img src='Anatomic Sciences -3.jpg'>
<img src='Anatomic Sciences -4.jpg'>,<img src='Anatomic Sciences -5.jpg'><img src='Anatomic Sciences -6.jpg'>
```

You could use the same pattern but include your text instead of an image reference in the CSV after the comma of each line.